# IOS8 App Crash EXC-CRASH (SIGABRT)

Tags: logging, ios8, crash

i´m creating an app - it works so far, but "sometimes" it crashed. It can happen after 1 hour, 2 hours, 10 minutes. I don´t have an idea, where the problem is. Can someone help me out? Here is the crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: 41C72E45-2D38-47AF-89A7-1666846B4D13
CrashReporter Key:   7b23272467a57c9e510d7991d4e1de0661d90c5d
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:             TQ [15248]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/F50B5713-F039-48A5-A1F4-E27ACE8FE2B9/TQ.app/TQ
Identifier:          com.tq.tq
Version:             5.2995 (5.30)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-05-10 21:14:03.574 +0200
Launch Time:         2015-05-10 20:58:33.167 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F70)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198237270 0x19821c000 + 111216
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d516c 0x1982d0000 + 20844
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001981aeb14 0x19814c000 + 404244
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001982723e0 0x198260000 + 74720
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001982712f4 0x198260000 + 70388
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018615a44c 0x186154000 + 25676
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186159f88 0x186154000 + 24456
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001862317d4 0x186154000 + 907220
8   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018615d2d0 0x186154000 + 37584
9   GraphicsServices                0x000000018f9736f8 0x18f968000 + 46840
10  UIKit                           0x000000018ad22fa8 0x18acac000 + 487336
11  TQ                              0x00000001000c99ac 0x100010000 + 760236
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019811ea04 0x19811c000 + 10756

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019821cc24 0x19821c000 + 3108
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198101e6c 0x1980f0000 + 73324
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001980f3998 0x1980f0000 + 14744

Thread 2 name:  GAIThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019821ce0c 0x19821c000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019821cc84 0x19821c000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186233720 0x186154000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186231674 0x186154000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018615d2d0 0x186154000 + 37584
5   Foundation                      0x00000001870954c4 0x187088000 + 54468
6   Foundation                      0x00000001870ef80c 0x187088000 + 423948
7   TrackQuiz                       0x0000000100230508 0x100010000 + 2229512
8   Foundation                      0x000000018717ddb4 0x187088000 + 1007028
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3dc4 0x1982d0000 + 15812
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3d20 0x1982d0000 + 15648
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d0ef4 0x1982d0000 + 3828

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.coreaudio.AQClient
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019821ce0c 0x19821c000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019821cc84 0x19821c000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186233720 0x186154000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186231674 0x186154000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018615d2d0 0x186154000 + 37584
5   AudioToolbox                    0x000000018577a278 0x185740000 + 238200
6   AudioToolbox                    0x000000018576c51c 0x185740000 + 181532
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3dc4 0x1982d0000 + 15812
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3d20 0x1982d0000 + 15648
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d0ef4 0x1982d0000 + 3828

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019821ce0c 0x19821c000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019821cc84 0x19821c000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186233720 0x186154000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186231674 0x186154000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018615d2d0 0x186154000 + 37584
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000185c3e890 0x185ba0000 + 649360
6   Foundation                      0x000000018717ddb4 0x187088000 + 1007028
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3dc4 0x1982d0000 + 15812
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3d20 0x1982d0000 + 15648
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d0ef4 0x1982d0000 + 3828

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198237498 0x19821c000 + 111768
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186239124 0x186154000 + 938276
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3dc4 0x1982d0000 + 15812
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3d20 0x1982d0000 + 15648
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d0ef4 0x1982d0000 + 3828

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019821ce0c 0x19821c000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019821cc84 0x19821c000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186233720 0x186154000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186231674 0x186154000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018615d2d0 0x186154000 + 37584
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001861af358 0x186154000 + 373592
6   CoreMotion                      0x0000000186b68364 0x186b20000 + 295780
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3dc4 0x1982d0000 + 15812
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3d20 0x1982d0000 + 15648
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d0ef4 0x1982d0000 + 3828

Thread 7 name:  WebThread
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019821ce0c 0x19821c000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019821cc84 0x19821c000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186233720 0x186154000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186231674 0x186154000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018615d2d0 0x186154000 + 37584
5   WebCore                         0x0000000194b58890 0x194aa8000 + 723088
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3dc4 0x1982d0000 + 15812
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3d20 0x1982d0000 + 15648
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d0ef4 0x1982d0000 + 3828

Thread 8 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198237078 0x19821c000 + 110712
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d2f28 0x1982d0000 + 12072
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000019721ccac 0x197214000 + 36012
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000187751620 0x187738000 + 103968
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018774cb9c 0x187738000 + 84892
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3dc4 0x1982d0000 + 15812
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3d20 0x1982d0000 + 15648
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d0ef4 0x1982d0000 + 3828

Thread 9 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198237078 0x19821c000 + 110712
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d2f28 0x1982d0000 + 12072
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000019721ccac 0x197214000 + 36012
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001879faedc 0x187738000 + 2895580
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001879faf80 0x187738000 + 2895744
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018774cb9c 0x187738000 + 84892
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3dc4 0x1982d0000 + 15812
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3d20 0x1982d0000 + 15648
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d0ef4 0x1982d0000 + 3828

Thread 10 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019821ce0c 0x19821c000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019821cc84 0x19821c000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186233720 0x186154000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186231674 0x186154000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018615d2d0 0x186154000 + 37584
5   WebCore                         0x0000000194b8c9ac 0x194aa8000 + 936364
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018774cb9c 0x187738000 + 84892
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3dc4 0x1982d0000 + 15812
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3d20 0x1982d0000 + 15648
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d0ef4 0x1982d0000 + 3828

Thread 11 name:  WebCore: LocalStorage
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198237078 0x19821c000 + 110712
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d2f28 0x1982d0000 + 12072
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001877517bc 0x187738000 + 104380
3   WebCore                         0x00000001956e232c 0x194aa8000 + 12821292
4   WebCore                         0x0000000194c54ff8 0x194aa8000 + 1757176
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018774cb9c 0x187738000 + 84892
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3dc4 0x1982d0000 + 15812
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3d20 0x1982d0000 + 15648
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d0ef4 0x1982d0000 + 3828

Thread 12 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019821ce0c 0x19821c000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019821cc84 0x19821c000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186233720 0x186154000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186231674 0x186154000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018615d2d0 0x186154000 + 37584
5   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x0000000184bd902c 0x184bc0000 + 102444
6   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x0000000184bcba0c 0x184bc0000 + 47628
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3dc4 0x1982d0000 + 15812
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3d20 0x1982d0000 + 15648
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d0ef4 0x1982d0000 + 3828

Thread 13 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.remote
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019821ce0c 0x19821c000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019821cc84 0x19821c000 + 3204
2   MediaToolbox                    0x000000018874c848 0x188740000 + 51272
3   CoreMedia                       0x0000000186a979ac 0x186a5c000 + 244140
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3dc4 0x1982d0000 + 15812
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3d20 0x1982d0000 + 15648
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d0ef4 0x1982d0000 + 3828

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198237c78 0x19821c000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d12d8 0x1982d0000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d0eec 0x1982d0000 + 3820

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198237c78 0x19821c000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d12d8 0x1982d0000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d0eec 0x1982d0000 + 3820

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198237c78 0x19821c000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d12d8 0x1982d0000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d0eec 0x1982d0000 + 3820

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198237c78 0x19821c000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d12d8 0x1982d0000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d0eec 0x1982d0000 + 3820

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198237c78 0x19821c000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d12d8 0x1982d0000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d0eec 0x1982d0000 + 3820

Thread 19 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019821ce48 0x19821c000 + 3656
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001980fff3c 0x1980f0000 + 65340
2   MediaToolbox                    0x0000000188744b48 0x188740000 + 19272
3   CoreMedia                       0x0000000186a979ac 0x186a5c000 + 244140
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3dc4 0x1982d0000 + 15812
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d3d20 0x1982d0000 + 15648
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001982d0ef4 0x1982d0000 + 3828

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000001   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000000000035  x13: 0x000000017b700560  x14: 0x000000017056e1c0  x15: 0x00000001745720c0
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x000000018acb5674  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000019c10f310  x21: 0x0000000000000001  x22: 0x0000000198279036  x23: 0x000000017b700550
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000000000001  x26: 0x000000017b700550  x27: 0x000000019873df50
   x28: 0x000000016e836000  fp: 0x000000016fdee220   lr: 0x00000001982d5170
    sp: 0x000000016fdee200   pc: 0x0000000198237270 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say run a debug version under the debugger for an hour or two until it crashes and start debugging.

The usual things to do to reduce the chances of a crash: Turn on all reasonable warnings and fix the causes of warnings. Use the static analyzer and fix all problems that it finds. Create plenty of useful unit tests and check that they all succeed. Make sure you know the consequences of multi-threading and use sequential queues or synchronization when needed.

Comment: You´re right! But no ERROR appears, when i rund the app in the debug mode. I also have no warnings.

Comment: Can you let me know the best practice for "turn on all reasonable warnings"